# Javascript variables-- What does it mean when add () after the variable?

Tags: javascript

I just started learning js from [EloquentJavascript](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html#p33f5c110)
I need 2 answers to help me pass this example:

```
function makeAddFunction(amount) {
  function add(number) {
    return number + amount;
  }
  return add;
}

var addTwo = makeAddFunction(2);
var addFive = makeAddFunction(5);
show(addTwo(1) + addFive(1));
```

### Question 1:

Can we just add () after variable meaning to add argument to the function that the variable represent? like addTwo(1) means makeAddFunction(1)?

### Question 2:

makeAddFunction(2) means amount = 2, then what's the value for number? If I pick a section of the above example,  what will return in the following section?

```
function makeAddFunction(2) {
  function add(number) {
    return number + 2;
  }
  return add;
}
```

Comment: Did you try the code? see what it does.

Comment: the first example returns 9, the 2nd example returns ReferenceError: amount is not defined.

Comment: You're doing something wrong. show us a fiddle. And the question is too localized, You're asking a question about a concrete code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can we just add () after variable meaning to add argument to the function that the variable represent? like addTwo(1) means makeAddFunction(1)

Nope. `addTwo(1)` equals to `makeAddFunction(2)(1)`

> makeAddFunction(2) means amount = 2, then what's the value for number? in the following example2, what will return?

You pass it additionally, when call `addTwo` or `addFive`

Comment: So, when there's additional var inside a function, we can pass additional value like makeAddFunction(2)(1) ?

Comment: @Jenny: it's not additional var. `makeAddFunction` returns a function, that accepts one argument. So result of `makeAddFunction(1)` call is another function, that accepts one argument

Comment: I see. so, in this case, I need to give argument to the another function by adding the argument to the var addTwo and addFive?

Comment: @Jenny: yes, because they are functions

Comment: Thanks! This helps get my head straight.

Answer (score 2):

Both of your questions are answered if you look at the return type of `makeAddFunction(amount)`. You are returning a function `add(number)`. So by defining `addTwo` as `makeAddFunction(2)`, you are returning the following function:

```
function add(number) {
    return number+2;
}
```

If `addTwo` and `addFive` are function, show(...) will show: `9`. (2+1)+(5+1)=9

Comment: addTwo and addFive are not function. they are variables defined just below the function makeAddFunction. That's why I doubt if I can pass argument through variable by adding () after variable.

Comment: @Jenny: they **are** functions. You can store function in a variable. `var foo = function() { return '123'; }; alert(foo());` --- this will alert `123`